# Open Same VSCode File Buffer in Multiple Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to open the same file buffer(editor) in multiple VSCode windows? This is not the same as opening the same file more than once. In the later, if you forget to save edits in one window, and then save different edits in another window, you end up with conflicts. I'm curious if it's possible to have the same buffer opened (mirrored?) in different windows, such that the view is identical for that file across all windows. So if I make changes in the file (even before saving), those changes also show in every other window that the buffer is opened in. I've searched around a lot but can't really find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Split Editor command: `Ctrl + \`.

You can also use the icon in the top right. Hold `Alt` to split down.

[image: Split editor]